# Running clustering algorithms in ELKI

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, k-means, elki

I need to run a k-medoids clustering algorithm by using ELKI programmatically. I have a similarity matrix that I wish to input to the algorithm.

Is there any code snippet available for how to run ELKI algorithms?
I basically need to know how to create `Database` and `Relation` objects, create a custom distance function, and read the algorithm output.

Unfortunately the ELKI tutorial (http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial) focuses on the GUI version and on implementing new algorithms, and trying to write code by looking at the Javadoc is frustrating.

If someone is aware of any easy-to-use library for k-medoids, that's probably a good answer to this question as well.

Comment: Have a look at the unit tests: http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/trunk/test/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki that is where I copy when I need to run it from Java. I mostly use the command line and GUI though, they are very powerful.

Comment: As for the your similarity matrix, see http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/HowTo/PrecomputedDistances

Comment: Try writing code by looking at code. It's included with ELKI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do appreciate documentation contributions! (**Update:** I have turned this post into a [new ELKI tutorial entry](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/HowTo/InvokingELKIFromJava) for now.)

ELKI does advocate to **not embed it in other applications Java** for a number of reasons. This is why we recommend using the MiniGUI (or the command line it constructs). Adding custom code is best done e.g. as a custom `ResultHandler` or just by using the `ResultWriter` and parsing the resulting text files.

If you *really* want to embed it in your code (there are a number of situations where it is useful, in particular when you need multiple relations, and want to evaluate different index structures against each other), here is the basic setup for getting a `Database` and `Relation`:

```
// Setup parameters:
ListParameterization params = new ListParameterization();
params.addParameter(FileBasedDatabaseConnection.INPUT_ID, filename);
// Add other parameters for the database here!

// Instantiate the database:
Database db = ClassGenericsUtil.parameterizeOrAbort(
    StaticArrayDatabase.class,
    params);
// Don't forget this, it will load the actual data...
db.initialize();

Relation<DoubleVector> vectors = db.getRelation(TypeUtil.DOUBLE_VECTOR_FIELD);
Relation<LabelList> labels = db.getRelation(TypeUtil.LABELLIST);
```

If you want to program more general, use `NumberVector<?>`.

### Why we do (currently) not recommend using ELKI as a "library":

1. The API is still changing a lot. We keep on adding options, and we **cannot (yet) provide a stable API**. The command line / MiniGUI / Parameterization is much more stable, because of the handling of default values - the parameterization only lists the non-default parameters, so only if these change you'll notice.

   In the code example above, note that I also used this pattern. A change to the parsers, database etc. will likely *not* affect this program!
2. **Memory usage:** data mining is quite memory intensive. If you use the MiniGUI or command line, you have a good *cleanup* when the task is finished. If you invoke it from Java, changes are *really high* that you keep some reference somewhere, and end up leaking *lots* of memory. So **do not use above pattern without ensuring that the objects are properly cleaned up when you are done**!

   By running ELKI from the command line, you get two things for free:

   1. no memory leaks. When the task is finished, the process quits and frees all memory.
   2. no need to rerun it twice for the same data. Subsequent analysis does not need to rerun the algorithm.
3. ELKI is **not designed as embeddable library for good reasons**. ELKI has tons of options and functionality, and this comes at a price, both in runtime (although it can easily outperform R and Weka, for example!) memory usage and in particular in code complexity.
   ELKI was **designed for research in data mining algorithms**, not for making them easy to include in arbitrary applications. Instead, if you have a particular problem, you should use ELKI to find out *which* approach works good, then *reimplement that approach in an optimized manner for your problem*.

### Best ways of using ELKI

Here are some tips and tricks:

1. Use the MiniGUI to build a command line. Note that in the logging window of the "GUI" it shows the corresponding command line parameters - **running ELKI from command line is easy to script**, and can easily be distributed to multiple computers e.g. via Grid Engine.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   for k in $( seq 3 39 ); do
       java -jar elki.jar KDDCLIApplication \
           -dbc.in whatever \
           -algorithm clustering.kmeans.KMedoidsEM \
           -kmeans.k $k \
           -resulthandler ResultWriter -out.gzip \
           -out output/k-$k 
   done
   ```
2. Use indexes. For many algorithms, index structures can make a huge difference!
   (But you *need* to do some research which indexes can be used for which algorithms!)
3. Consider using the extension points such as `ResultWriter`. It may be the easiest for you to hook into this API, then use `ResultUtil` to select the results that you want to **output in your own preferred format** or analyze:

   ```
   List<Clustering<? extends Model>> clusterresults =
       ResultUtil.getClusteringResults(result);
   ```
4. To identify objects, use labels and a `LabelList` relation. The default parser will do this when it sees text along the numerical attributes, i.e. a file such as

   ```
   1.0 2.0 3.0 ObjectLabel1
   ```

   will make it easy to identify the object by its label!

**UPDATE:** See [ELKI tutorial created out of this post](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/HowTo/InvokingELKIFromJava) for updates.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I needed something off-the-shelf now but easily embeddable, so I'll skip for this time, but I will do keep ELKI in mind. Glad to ask a question that led to a new tutorial :)

Answer (score 3):

ELKI's documentation is pretty sparse (I don't know why they don't include a simple "hello world" program in the examples)

You could try Java-ML. Its documentation is a bit more user friendly, and it does have K-medoid.

Clustering example with Java-ML |
http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/content/clustering-basics

K-medoid | 
http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/api/0.1.7/

Comment: Feel free to contribute documentation. Documentation is usually best when it is contributed, because the author of the software usually tends to think "inside his own box".

Comment: I already tried a toy example with JavaML, but i get a weird java.util.NoSuchElementException. I should probably write a question about it.
I am a bit frustrated by all these libraries right now, so I think I will implement K-Medoids by myself...