# Using ELKI on custom objects and making sense of results

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, elki

I am trying to use [ELKI's SLINK implementation](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.5.5/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/clustering/SLINK.html) of hierarchical clustering in my program.

I have a set of objects (of my own type) that need to be clustered. For that, I convert them to feature vectors before clustering.

This is how I currently got it to run and produce some result (code is in Scala):

```
val clusterer = new SLINK(CosineDistanceFunction.STATIC, 3)
val connection = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(featureVectors)
val database = new StaticArrayDatabase(connection, null)
database.initialize()

val result = clusterer.run(database).asInstanceOf[Clustering[_ <: Model]]
```

Now, the result is a `Clustering` that contains elements of type `Model`. I can output them, but I don't know how to make sense of this result, especially since `SLINK` returns models of type `DendrogramModel` which does not seem to be parametrizable.

Specifically, how can I link the results back to my original elements (the ones from which I created the variable `featureVectors` earlier)?

I assume I need to create some kind of custom model or somehow maintain some link to the original elements through initialization and execution of the algorithm to retrieve from the result. I cannot find where to get started on this though.

I am aware that embedding ELKI into own programs is discouraged. However, it seems that calling ELKI in some other way would not be any different: I need to cluster and map the results back to my objects during runtime of my program.

Answer (score 2):

The `DendrogramModel` does not include the objects in the cluster. Models are additional **meta** data on the clusters.

Use the [`getIDs()`](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.5.5/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/data/Cluster.html#getIDs%28%29) method to access the members of a [`Cluster`](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.5.5/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/data/Cluster.html) instance.

Comment: Okay, so I get the members of a cluster using `getIDs()`. Following [your example on running algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326505/running-clustering-algorithms-in-elki/15334879#15334879) I acquire a `Relation` by calling `db.getRelation(TypeUtil.DOUBLE_VECTOR_FIELD)` and can then `get()` my vectors from it. Is that workflow correct? I am still missing a possibility to get back to my original objects. Can I somehow use my own `DoubleVector` subclass (that contains a reference to my data) when initializing and running the algorithm?

Comment: Yes, get the relation of the desired type, then get the instances by their DBID. Avoid making `DBID` objects, you can call `get` on the iterator which is much cheaper.
Many algorithms will run with any class that you have a distance function for. Most distance functions are defined for arbitrary `NumberVector`s. So either implement your own distance function (for your data type), or implement the `NumberVector` interface on your data type, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I think I understand how to plug in my `DistanceFunction`. But the rest is exactly the problem: How _can_ I have an algorithm run on custom classes? Do I have to implement my own `DatabaseConnection` for that? All existing implementations seem not that generic.

Comment: Implementing a `DatabaseConnection` is probably the easiest way to get custom data into the ELKI database layer. If the data is file resident, it may however suffice to implement a `Parser` instead, or a `NumberVector.Factory` (if the existing parser can be reused, but should produce different objects).